# How does StackOverflow store its data? RDBMS or NoSQL?

Tags: discussion, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Does StackOverflow use MySQL, PostgreSQL, CouchDB, Mongo, or something else, some combination of the above, etc? I'm curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network):

> - **Database** [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/default.aspx) running [Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/34846/in-place-upgrade-from-windows-server-standard-to-enterprise-or-datacenter)
>     ...
> - **Data Access Layer** [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)